# Append information at the end of the URL

Tags: django, templates, django-urls

I have an application which is very similar to forum. Users can participate in posting content. When user click on a topic it goes to that topics page which shows all the discussion related to that topic. I have a side bar just like in the stackoverflow where it shows `similar questions` which shows topics related to the title of the topic in the current page.

Here is the sidebar template code:

```
<div class="box">
    <h2>{% trans %}Related Topics{% endtrans %}</h2>
    <div class="topic-related">
        {% for thread_dict in similar_threads.data() %}
        <p>
            <a href="{{ thread_dict.url }}">{{ thread_dict.title|escape }}</a>
        </p>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

I have an application that tracks user clicks. Assume that user went to a topic and after seeing the related topics she clicks on a topics and go to that page. But I have no way of distinguishing if the user directly went to this topics other than using related topics section.

So I thought may be I can add something like `fromRelatedTOpics` to the end of the url. What is the best way to accomplish this?

```
<a href="{{ thread_dict.url(fromRelatedTopics) }}">{{ thread_dict.title|escape }}</a>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The keyword you are looking for is *referer*. If the user clicked a link to your site, the referer may tell you where he came from (this depends on the browser setting). To access the referer from a view, you have to access the `META` attribute of the request, i.e.:

```
request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
```

You may want to look into [this django snippet](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1474/) to get some inspiration.

If you want this information inside the template, you can try this:

```
{{ request.META.HTTP_REFERER }}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to redirect all clicks to "related topics" to a single view, also pass the related topic id (or any unique value which can identify that topic in backend) to this view.

Now whenever this view is executed you can safely assume that someone clicked on "related topic", so record this behavior. Using *referer* (as described by @steinar) you can also record the parent page url from where relative link was clicked.

After recording the behavior you can redirect user to "related topic" using the unique id passed to this view.